# loading groups of images and labeling them

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have a database of cats and dogs that I need to classify them. I would like to load all images inside my dataset folder and generate labels according to class, for example:

```
Group 1/
       Pets 1/
          cats/
            breeds_1_cats001.jpeg
            breeds_1_cats002.jpeg
     
           dogs/
            breeds_1_dogs001.jpeg
            breeds_1_dogs002.jpeg
      Pets 2/
          cats/
            breeds_2_cats001.jpeg
            breeds_2_cats002.jpeg
     
          dogs/
            breeds_2_dogs001.jpeg
            breeds_2_dogs002.jpeg
Group 2/
      Pets 1/
          cats/
            breeds_3_cats001.jpeg
            breeds_3_cats002.jpeg
           
          dogs/
            breeds_3_dogs001.jpeg
            breeds_3_dogs002.jpeg
      Pets 2/
          cats/
            breeds_4_cats001.jpeg
            breeds_4_cats002.jpeg
           
           dogs/
            breeds_4_dogs001.jpeg
            breeds_4_dogs002.jpeg
Group 3/
       Pets 1/
          cats/
            breeds_5_cats001.jpeg
            breeds_5_cats002.jpeg
           
          dogs/
            breeds_5_dogs001.jpeg
            breeds_5_dogs002.jpeg
      Pets 2/
          cats/
            breeds_6_cats001.jpeg
            breeds_6_cats002.jpeg
           
          dogs/
            breeds_6_dogs001.jpeg
            breeds_6_dogs002.jpeg
```

What i would like to do is load every image inside my dataset into an array and afterwards create a y label for each pet.

What i would like to achieve is have an array Y that has in respect to X holds in found order the image labels, example:

```
Y = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0].
```

However, due to the amount of images that I have, it's not pratical for manually create this labels, how can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, first read all the files in your data set folder and iterate through the file paths. If the path contains `cats`, append the cat label and if not, append the dog label:

```
import glob

images_paths = []
labels = []

files = glob.glob('./Dataset/**/*.jpeg', recursive=True)

for file_path in files:
    if 'cats' in file_path:
        labels.append(1)
    else:
        labels.append(0)
```

Label 0 - Dogs
Label 1 - Cats